# Applications of RSAES-OAEP Cryptography

Tags: rsa

I am trying to do a project on RSAES-OAEP cryptography.Can anyone advice me any good applications where this can be used where there will be a lot to learn about in a programming and application perspective?

Answer (score 1):

RSA is good for short messages, so think about applications involving short messages. e.g.

- Key encryption. i.e. use RSA to encrypt an AES key for transport
- Credit card data. i.e. encrypting a credit card number for transmission